# how to use if else condition in joltspecification in Apache NiFi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am preparing the joltspecification where I need to implement if else condition. But I am unable to achieve expected output.Please help me out.

Note:

1. if `credits_type` is equals to `MARGIN` or `null` then `cost` = `pretax`
2. else `cost` + `creditsamount` = `pretax`

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "cost": "10",
    "credits_amount": "5",
    "credits_type": "MARGIN"
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "cost": "10",
    "credits_amount": "5",
    "credits_type": "MARGIN",
    "pretax": "10"
  }
]
```

- Here `pretax` is **10** because the `credits_type` = `MARGIN`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "credits_type": ["=notNull", "MARGIN"], // if it's Null(eg. else case of notNull) then assign MARGIN in order to combine the cases
        "xx_": "=intSum(@(1,credits_amount),@(1,cost))",
        "xx": "=toString(@(1,xx_))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "credits_type": {
          "@": "[&2].&",
          "MARGIN": { "@2,cost": "[&3].pretax" },
          "*": { "@2,xx": "[&3].pretax" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the extra attributes "xx" and "xx_"
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "x*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Excuse me for editing. I ran your spec and I didn't see the `pretax` field in the desired output. I just edit the last spec in your code. Do you agree with last one spec?

Comment: The first jolt spec object is a very nice idea.

Comment: Please run your spec again. You can't see `pretax` now. see `Expected output` in the question.

Comment: Ooo OK, missed by mistake I had kept a `pretax` attribute within the input, thank you warning me @MohammadrezaKhedri

Comment: It's not a mistake Man. The main solution in your spec is great.